# FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference() to child node and list key value pairs under that child

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to access the **shrubs** child and under each unique key under shrubs, access the key value pairs e.g. **key**: *ShrubbedWord* **value**: *yfyj*

[image: Click here to view a screenshot of my firebase tree structure]

I've tried this but I get nothing:-

```
postsData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Shrubs");

        ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    for (DataSnapshot dttSnapshot2 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Log.d("mylog", "" + dttSnapshot2.getKey().toString() + ":" + dttSnapshot2.getValue().toString());
                    }
            }
```

Now when I try this:

```
postsData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    for (DataSnapshot dttSnapshot2 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Log.d("mylog", "" + dttSnapshot2.getKey().toString() + ":" + dttSnapshot2.getValue().toString());
                    }
            }
```

My log returns a whole bunch of data from birthday all the way to Shrubs which I don't need. Just want the data in the Shrubs child in key value pairs.

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("unknown").child("Shrubs");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for(DataSnasphot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
     String name=datas.child("ShrubbedWord").getValue().toString();
    } 
 }

@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {


    }
   });
```

You need to go from top to bottom, in the image that you provided there is a child node that you added red lines on it so we do not see it.

I have named it in the code as `child("unknown")` , but in your code name it as the name that it is written in the database.

After that you write `child("Shrubs")`, then your dataSnapshot will be at the location of the Shrubs child node. Then you can iterate inside the push id to be able to retrieve the attributes and the values inside of it.

Comment: Sorry had to hide the child node, its a unique user id from Facebook Graph API, let me try try this out see what happens.

Comment: yes it is fine, but it needs to be in the `child(userid).child("Shrubs")` like that

Comment: Since I'm using Facebook's Graph API, I decided to set the child node to the unique user ID which works fine, now problem is, I want to get the same for the second child node which is another unique user ID, how do i go about this?

Comment: since it is the unique user id, then the user needs to be logged in the phone to be able to use it, then just added it in a variable and then add the variable in the child , `child(useruid).child("Shrubs")` there is no other way